# Removing duplication for this MYSQL union query

Tags: mysql, union

I have a query with duplicate expressions in it. Could it be written more compact?

```
select id from `vacature_saved_searches`
       where `saved_search_interval` = 1 and 
              DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) BETWEEN 2 AND 6 and 
              `last_processing_started_datetime` < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
UNION
select id from `vacature_saved_searches` 
       where `saved_search_interval` = 2 and 
              DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) IN (2, 4, 6) and 
             `last_processing_started_datetime` < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
UNION
select id from `vacature_saved_searches` 
       where `saved_search_interval` = 3 and 
              DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 3 AND 
              `last_processing_started_datetime` < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
UNION
select id from `vacature_saved_searches` 
       where `saved_search_interval` = 4 and 
              DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 3 and 
              DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 and 
              `last_processing_started_datetime` < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of DISTINCT and rephrasing the query to use OR clauses rather than unions:

```
select DISTINCT id from `vacature_saved_searches`
   where ((`saved_search_interval` = 1 and DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) BETWEEN 2 AND 6) OR
         (`saved_search_interval` = 2 and DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) IN (2, 4, 6)) OR 
         (`saved_search_interval` = 3 and DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 3) OR 
         (`saved_search_interval` = 4 and DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 3 and 
             DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 7))
         AND `last_processing_started_datetime` < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that much better.  Also, for this exact query the results should be the same, but if there were overlaps between the 4 queries, you would get duplicates in your original UNION.

```
select id 
from `vacature_saved_searches` 
where `last_processing_started_datetime` < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND
    ((`saved_search_interval` = 1 and DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) BETWEEN 2 AND 6) OR
     (`saved_search_interval` = 2 and DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) IN (2, 4, 6)) OR
     (`saved_search_interval` = 3 and DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 3) OR
     (`saved_search_interval` = 4 and DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 3 and DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 7))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Why union when its the same table?

Why not just

```
select id from `vacature_saved_searches`
  where 
((`saved_search_interval` = 1 and 
              DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) BETWEEN 2 AND 6) 
or
(`saved_search_interval` = 2 and 
              DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) IN (2, 4, 6))
or 
(`saved_search_interval` = 3 and 
              DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 3)
or
(`saved_search_interval` = 4 and 
              DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 3 and 
              DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 7))
and `last_processing_started_datetime` < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
```